# How to define basic Python structures?

Tags: python, racket

I'm coming to Python from Racket. In Racket, I would define a `Point` structure like this:

```
(struct Point (x y) #:transparent)
```

A point is now a structure with two fields named `x` and `y`. I can compare two structures for (deep) equality by calling `equal?`.

What is the equivalent in Python? It looks to me like I have to write *twelve* lines:

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x;
        self.y = y;

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return ((type(other) is Point)
          and self.x == other.x
          and self.y == other.y)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not(self == other)
```

... but surely there's an easier way?

Comment: To nitpick, you need a `#:transparent` on your `struct` definition in `#lang racket` to get deep equality, but that doesn’t change the number of lines it takes.

Comment: @JohnClements, you can just define __eq__ and __lt__ and you your objects will be comparables using `>, >=, <. <=, !=` and `==`

Comment: Note that your Python code has room for a lot of custom behavior, not all of which is necessary for every class. Also, you only had to _write_ ten lines.

Comment: @AlexisKing bien sur .

Comment: Side-notes: 1. If you're on Python 3, you don't need to define `__ne__` on classes that don't inherit a `__ne__` they need to override; `__ne__` has a default implementation in terms of `__eq__` that works correctly. 2. If you're on Py2, you want the canonical `__ne__`, `def __ne__(self, other):`, `ret = self.__eq__(other)`, `return ret if ret is NotImplemented else not ret`. That canonical form handles `NotImplemented` correctly (for `__eq__` that use it to allow the other side of the comparison a shot), and can be copied into 99% of Py2 classes with `__eq__` without changes.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf: `__eq__` and `__lt__` are sufficient only if you're on Python 3 (with default `__ne__` implementation) and decorate the class with `functools.total_ordering` to fill in the other rich comparison methods for you. Python built-ins (`list.sort`, `sorted`, `min`, `max`, etc.) stick to `__lt__` for comparisons, but if users of your class can't do `obj1 > obj2`, they'll be kind of annoyed. (Caveat: On Py2, for backcompat reasons, the built-ins will sometimes use `__le__` by preference, and fall back to `__lt__` if it's missing, in Py3 `__lt__` is king)

Comment: @ShadowRanger, thank you for your explanation. I forgot to include that the class should be decorated.

Comment: I'll use this as an example the next time someone asks what macros can be used for ;-)

Comment: You'd better believe I'm writing Racket to generate Python code right now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, well, if you need an entire class to represent your data type, then you will have to rely on the `__eq__` and related dunder methods. However, in this particular case, a Pythonista would use a `namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x','y'])
```

Which will inherit all that from `tuple`.

Comment: Huh. Stupid StackOverflow didn't alert me to your new answer, wasted my time on redundant info. I'll leave it in place only because it includes the additional info on mutability and the behavior of equality testing.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yeah, you got an upvote from me for including the warning that `(Point(1, 2) == (1, 2) ` evaluates to `True`!

Comment: Nice! Extra upvote for alerting me to the term "dunder methods." The $64K followup question is whether teachers in later courses will be alarmed that all of my students use named tuples instead of classes. Many thanks.

Comment: @JohnClements well, maybe their employers will thank you! I'm a bit of a partisan when it comes to the topic of the over-use of classes. Essentially, I subscribe to most of the opinions given [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)

Comment: There’s more than the `Point(1, 2) == (1, 2)` gotcha: if you do `Vector = namedtuple('Vector', ['angle', 'magnitude'])`, then `Point(1, 2) == Vector(1, 2)` is `True`, even though they have very different meanings!

Comment: @AlexisKing Yes, although a `namedtuple` can often substitute, it's not a perfect fit.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need mutability, the simplest way to make basic classes of this sort is `collections.namedtuple`:

```
import collections

Point = collections.namedtuple('Point', 'x y')
```

That's it. You can just make `Point` objects with `pt = Point(1, 2)` or the like, and they work like two-tuples, but they also let you access them via named attributes, e.g. `pt.x`, `pt.y`.

The equality checking will be a little looser (`Point(1, 2) == (1, 2)` evaluates to `True`, because all `namedtuple`s are subclasses of `tuple` and will compare using `tuple` rules, and in fact, different subclasses of `tuple` that don't override the comparison methods will compare equal to each other if they have the same values), but given that `tuple`s are typically used as anonymous lightweight "classes", this is often what you want.

If you need to customize some behavior (adding functionality, or make the type comparisons stricter), you can make a custom class inherit from a `namedtuple` to get the basic features for free, then customize the bits you care about, e.g., to prevent it testing equal to non-`Point` types, you can do:

```
class Point(collections.namedtuple('PointBase', 'x y')):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Point):
            return False
        return super().__eq__(other)

    # Sadly, tuple defines __ne__, so you must override it too to behave properly
    # You don't need the canonical __ne__ implementation that handles NotImplemented
    # though, since you're explicitly unfriendly to non-Point types
    def __ne__(self, other): return not (self == other)
```

Comment: I have a suspicion that a Racket programmer will find immutability to be a *feature* :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I'd never even heard of Racket until today; pure functional I take it? In which case, yeah, immutability is good.

Comment: @ShadowRanger No, not pure functional. Definitely functional-unless-you-have-a-good-reason, though.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, racket is a treat