# Struct-like Datatypes in Vanilla Python

Tags: python

Is there a simple way of creating data objects that are programmatically-similar (without necessarily the memory properties) to C-like `struct`'s in vanilla Python (2 or 3), without going through all the class stuff? I'm primarily interested in a quick-and-easy way of creating arbitrary datatypes and accessing their fields by name.

Something as simple as:

```
def Car:               # quick and easy definition
    milesPerGallon
    color

myCar = Car(10,"blue")  # instantiation
myCar.color = "red"     # ability to set by attribute name
print(myCar.MPG)        # ability to get by attribute name
```

Or, is the only real way of being able to do this using classes?

Comment: You may want to look at [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#collections.namedtuple)

Comment: I'm aware of classes, as noted in the post. I'll have a look at named tuple's though.

Comment: @StephenLasky, _data_ classes are fairly close to what you describe in your post. They're new in Python 3.7. I'll add an answer with an example.

Comment: @StephenLasky `namedtuple`'s are *class factories*, so no, you would always do this with a class, one way or another, in Python. Unless you use a container like a `dict`. But you you want a *type* then you need a class. All types are classes. *Everything* in python is an object.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42287579/how-to-define-basic-python-structures/42287634#42287634 although it didn't include 3.7 data classes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3.7's [data classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) offer something very much like what's described in your post:

```
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass
>>> 
>>> @dataclass
... class Car:
...     miles_per_gallon: float
...     color: str
... 
>>> my_car = Car(10, 'blue')
>>> my_car.color = 'red'
>>> 
>>> print(my_car.miles_per_gallon)
10
```

If you're on an older version of Python, [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#collections.namedtuple) might be a good fit (as AChampion points out in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52020039/354577)).

Answer (score 1):

@Chris provides a good example of `@dataclass`, and would recommend that approach if you are using 3.7.
This is what a `namedtuple` looks like:

```
In []:
from collections import namedtuple
Car = namedtuple('Car', ['mpg', 'color'])

my_car = Car(10, 'blue')
print(my_car.mpg)

Out[]:
10
```

The one limitation with `namedtuple` is you cannot change the values (much like a normal tuple)

Answer (score 0):

What about a dictionary?

```
myCar = {'mpg': 10, 'color': 'blue'}
myCar['color'] = 'red'
print(myCar['mpg'])
```